# staggered docker stack deployment

Tags: docker, docker-stack

I have created a docker image to run varnish. It is passed the varnish .vcl config file, custom ports are set up and it works. 
I am rolling out multiple containers on one server each with custom configs and ports. So I have written a `docker-compose.yml` file to define this. Using `docker stack deploy` I can get them all running.

The problem comes in if I want to tweak the docker image. 
Currently, I am updating versions in the `docker-compose.yml` file and re-running the `docker stack deploy` command which shuts down all of my dockers and starts them up again. 
I would like to stagger the re-deployment so they are updated one at a time, as doing these all at once causes a lot of load on the server which will only get worse as we scale.

How can I do this?
Is there maybe a better approach to this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Current docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  test-site-one:
    image: test/varnish:v7.3
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - /path/to/magento.vcl:/etc/varnish/default.vcl
  test-site-two:
    image: test/varnish:v7.3
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    volumes:
      - /path/to/magento.vcl:/etc/varnish/default.vcl
  test-site-three:
    image: test/varnish:v7.3
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    volumes:
      - /path/tp/magento.vcl:/etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an update_config in your Compose file as described here https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#update_config.

As per the documentation:

> Configures how the service should be updated. Useful for configuring rolling updates.
>
> - parallelism: The number of containers to update at a time.
> - delay: The time to wait between updating a group of containers.
> - failure_action: What to do if an update fails. One of continue, rollback, or pause (default: pause).
> - monitor: Duration after each task update to monitor for failure (ns|us|ms|s|m|h) (default 0s).
> - max_failure_ratio: Failure rate to tolerate during an update.
> - order: Order of operations during updates. One of stop-first (old task is stopped before starting new one), or start-first (new task is started first, and the running tasks briefly overlap) (default stop-first) Note: Only supported for v3.4 and higher.

`version: '3.4'
services:
  vote:
    image: dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote:before
    depends_on:
      - redis
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
        delay: 10s
        order: stop-first`

Comment: Hello, I think this doesn't work in my case because I have placed the different varnish containers as different services. (so they can have different configs & ports). 
I have pasted my testing docker-compose.yml in my question if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could split those services into their own `docker-compose_<num>.yml` files , then you would simply run the appropriate deploy command `docker stack deploy ms -c docker-compose_<num>.yml` . If they need to run sequentially then just put each deploy command in a script with sleep commands in between , if needed .

Comment: Then you can't use --prune